# Cancel previous post requests by using axios and axios cancel token

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I'm using a post request to retrieve some values from the server but when the user logs out I need to cancel the previously triggered requests to the server.

I'm using the Axios library to make the requests [axios - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

I'm triggering the post request like this:

```
class CancelService extends InternetService { 
    async triggerPostRequest(params),  {
        const response = await axios.post(`request`, params, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'x-access-token': 'abcd',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            cancelToken: this.manager.source.token,
        });
        const jsReponse = response.data;
        if (response.status === 200) {
            jsReponse.success = true;
            return jsReponse;
        }
        return {
            success: 'fail',
            message: response.message,
        };
    }
```

And when the user is going to log out of the App, I'm cancelling and refreshing the axios token like this.

```
const cancelService = new CancelService();
cancelService.cancelRequests();
cancelService.initilize();
```

The class CancelService looks like this:

```
class CancelService extends InternetService { 
    cancelRequests = () => {
    if (this.manager && this.manager.source) {
        this.manager.source.cancel({ message: 'all request cancelled.' });
    }
};
```

But it seems that the requests are not cancelled given that when I log in with the next user the results of the previous request are getting loaded.

UPDATE:

I don't have access to change the backend and also the code is legacy it is making a bunch of calls in a row I can't change that either.

Comment: if you have control to backend service, I think the easiest is applying a token in backend record to check whether the request is valid or not valid. Once logout, just send a post request to invalid those, as you are using axios - 1 time ajax, not sync connection

Comment: Thanks, that seems like a perfect solution but like you already said I don't have access to the backend service in my case I need to handle all the logic from the front-end only.